# drawViewHierarchyInRect when app in background

Tags: ios, objective-c, image, uiview, core-graphics

I have a code for make a screenshot of UIView:

```
UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(self.bounds.size, NO, [UIScreen mainScreen].scale);

[self drawViewHierarchyInRect:self.bounds afterScreenUpdates:YES];

UIImage *image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();

UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
return image;
```

but its not working, if app in background - UIImage is empty (not nil). For example, user start process for many UIView and want to send message in Fb while my app do this.

How can I fix that?

Comment: I have the same issue with my project. Any one has any idea?